# Version compatibility between selenium-server-standalone.jar and chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What is the version compatibility between chromedriver and selenium-server-standalone.jar?

In other words, does latest version of chromedriver work with latest version of selenium-server-standalone.jar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Chrome Driver itself is tied more to the version of Chrome available on the execution Node (where the browser is actually spawned and a test is ran).

If you refer to the [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/notes.txt), you'll see how the driver versions map to the various releases of Chrome itself.

The practice I have in place is as follows:

- I match my Selenium dependency (C#/Java language bindings) to the version of the selenium-server I run either locally or on my Grid.
- When I deploy a version of my test project that upgrades the Selenium dependency, I simply upgrade all my Grid VM's to the matching version (using JSON Node config really helps here, since all I have to do is stop the service, swap the jar, and relaunch with my JSON configs).
- Firefox Driver is built into Selenium, so no upgrade management there.  IE Driver has (at least historically) matched the minor version number of Selenium (for example, current IE Driver is 2.48.0 while Selenium is at 2.48.2), so I typically upgrade my IE driver whenever I upgrade my Selenium version.  The version of Chrome Driver I employ on any given Node will then correspond to whatever version of Chrome that particular Node has installed, though in my own case, this is typically the most recent version.

In short, it's more important to match the version of Chrome Driver to the version of Chrome under which you are testing.

Comment: So IIUC, It is imp that we match FFs with selenium-server jar and chromes with chromedriver. But as such there is no version dependency between selenium server jar and chromedriver. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.  If you always run tests against the latest FF, keeping with the latest selenium-server is best.  With Chrome, just make sure the driver provides support for your version under test.  Again, if you're always current, the latest ChromeDriver is best.  To keep things easy, I keep my Grid configured with the latest of everything, then if I need an older browser version, I'll run whatever tests on a service like SauceLabs since they have a large selection of platform/browser combos.

Comment: Actually, now that Selenium 3 is out, Firefox also has a driver - [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) that should be compatible with FF.

Comment: Wasted hours on a test runner trying to get the latest chromedriver working. Providing you don't need lots of crossbrowser testing, which I don't FF does the job. Even now in 2023 :)

Answer (score 1):

To add my 2 cents, `chromedriver` acts as the "bridge" between Chrome and the Selenium jar, so on one side you have the protocol and interface (WebDriver) that is backward compatible and on the other you have dependency on browser's releases which isn't. So compatibility wise @tim-slifer's answer is sufficient (except that now Firefox also has a [driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)).

However, when consuming the `selenium-server-standalone.jar`, you consume a binary. So versioning wise, keeping up to date with the [Selenium releases](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases) is simply to have fixes to new issues that rise with time - some of which related to the compatibility between `chromedriver` and Chrome.

So yes and no, there is some compatibility between the 2, although an old jar and bindings can work just fine with new browsers.